# Sending emailable.html testNG report on testSuite completion always sends old report

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, ui-automation

I have two test classes and one testng.xml where in one of the class I have created method with annotation @AfterSuite.
In @AfterSuite method I am sending emailable.html report to specific users.
On successful completion of test-suite execution it is sending older emailable.html file instead of latest file.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Email-able html will be generated once all the annotation task has been accomplished. Your code is sending the old file before the next i.e new html report is being generated. To verify this, delete the existing report and run your code, it will give you the exception .

Comment: @TanujVishnoi yes, But I wanted to send that report on my test suite completion. But my problem is solved now. Using Listener in testNG I implemented onFinish method to send email report on test suite completion and its working now.